# Gtk Change Font and font color for an application

Tags: gtk

I am having one Gtk+ and C application in which i want to set the font to some XYZ font type and font color to blue, for all the labels and text in the application how can i do this in one go, I have developed all the screen using Glade RAD tool, and currently i am doing this by calling following function for each label.

```
gtk_label_set_markup( label,"<span font='FONT NAME' foreground='#FFFFFF' size='large'><b>MY Text</b></span>");
```

So how can i tell the Gtk to use my font and font color for every label and for every widget in the application.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally considered bad form to do that; apps should respect the user's theme. That said, you can deploy a resource file with the settings you want to override in your application, and then use [gtk_rc_parse()](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-Resource-Files.html#gtk-rc-parse) to load the file at runtime.

Check out [GTK+ Resource Files documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-Resource-Files.html) for details.

Comment: The answer is somehow misleading. 
Apps should respect **user's preferences**. "*Theme*" is just his/hers general preference which must be used as a "startup option", but user should be free to change, at least some things (depending on the form). Imagine a world where office applications "respect" the theme and do not allow him/her to change font! Even web applications today have a "change font size" just in case (which will override the font size of the theme, which in turn can also be overridden, in most web browsers, by user pressing Ctrl+ or Ctrl-   ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to change the size of the font (because in the windows I don't see any common way how to modify general GTKMM's font size, and user wants bigger fonts because he has small screen).

This works, when called before displaying window:

```
style = formatString( "style \"my-style\" { font_name = \"Mono %i\" } class \"*\" style \"my-style\"", fontSize);
gtk_rc_parse_string( style );
```

This is a way to 'create application setting' and apply it on the fly.
By the way, class "*" means that all items will have this style applied.