# fvwm gvim menu size smaller than text size

Tags: vim, font-size

I am new to fvwm machine which is used by my new employers.
I am struggling in customizing gvim menu (File, Edit,etc) font size.
As you can see in the attached image, the font size are decent, but menu size is pretty small as compared to text font size.

How to solve this??

Reference Image:
[image]

Comment: You can't do this in a Vim setting, but you can probably add [some magic in the gtkrc file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2492861/660921) to do this ...

Answer (score 0):

gvim uses gnome gtk in the gnome version of gvim and in this case you can configure your environment using a .gtkrc file see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25043/what-is-this-gtkrc-file. As another answer pointed out for Gtk 2.x programs `~/.gtkrc-2.0` is the configuration file.

To modify your font see e.g.

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=846348
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=164044
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478303/38701

examples:

```
gtk-font-name = "Sans 12"
```

which gives you a Sans-Serif font with size 12

```
gtk-font-name = "DejaVu Sans 11"
```

which is more specific regarding the font and uses size 11

Answer (score -1):

Create .gtkrc-2.0 in your home directory if it isn't present already
and add:

```
gtk-font-name = "bitstream bold 16"
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: The effect was horrible due to the bold and big size. An explanation would be needed to make this a sensible answer. Just doing try & error with the given file and content won't cut it.